# Webpack-compiled CSS file is including Javascript variables and functions

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, webpack

We use a simple application of webpack/mix:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.js('resources/js/cpg.js', 'public/js')
.js('resources/js/editor.js', 'public/js')
.copy('resources/js/ckeditor/dist', 'public/js/editor')
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.sass('resources/sass/cpg.scss', 'public/css')
```

With webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
    },
},

// https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/
entry: './resources/js/editor.js',

// https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js/editor'),
    filename: 'editor.js'
},

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,

            use: ['raw-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,

            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                    options: {
                        injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
                        attributes: {
                            'data-cke': true
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: styles.getPostCssConfig({
                        themeImporter: {
                            themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark')
                        },
                        minify: true
                    })
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},

// Useful for debugging.
devtool: 'source-map',

// By default webpack logs warnings if the bundle is bigger than 200kb.
performance: { hints: false }
}
```

Prior to the addition of ckeditor, we had no troubles. But now that ckeditor has been added, the following JS now appears in our compiled cpg.css file:

```
 function webpackContext(req) {
    var id = webpackContextResolve(req);
    return __webpack_require__(id);
}
function webpackContextResolve(req) {
    if(!__webpack_require__.o(map, req)) {
        var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
        e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
        throw e;
    }
    return map[req];
}
webpackContext.keys = function webpackContextKeys() {
    return Object.keys(map);
};
webpackContext.resolve = webpackContextResolve;
module.exports = webpackContext;
webpackContext.id = "./node_modules/moment/locale sync recursive ^\\.\\/.*$";
```

Obviously, this is a problem. JS code does not belong in CSS files, and it trips up our SonarCloud quality gate (for good reason) so we can't deploy anything that's been compiled unless we manually edit the compiled files. Which mostly defeats the purpose of having them.

Further backstory: the section of our project that uses CKEditor was completed by a contractor. So, all of this was merged into our project before we saw that compiled files were improper. The contractor is no longer with the company, so I'm trying to debug on my own and getting nowhere. It seems to be an exceedingly rare bug for Webpack to place JS code in a CSS file.

Progress update: Removing the ckeditor references has no impact. The Webpack just seems to be broken now. Comprehensive node_modules re-install had no effect. It's just broken.

Issue appears to be a copy of https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/1976. Upgrading to Mix 6 creates an absolutely absurd amount of problems for my project, so this will just go unresolved.

Followed the instructions here: https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/2633#issuecomment-802023077 I was able to resolve the problem.

Comment: Does webpack create the file public/css/cpg.css everytime? Sounds to me like there is a leftover invalid file somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I delete the cpg.css file each time I've tried re-compiling it and it is always compiled the same way. Changing the order of the mix compiling (re-arranging the lines in webpack.mix.js) doesn't have any impact either.

I think you're right, but it looks like code that belongs in an internal webpack file, not one of the compiled ones. None of our JS files employ any of the identified JS code.

Comment: I had the same error on angular, my solution was add window.moment = moment in polyfills.browser.ts

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to this https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/8112
A solution there suggests this change

```
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'style-loader',
                options: {
                    injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
                    attributes: {
                        'data-cke': true
                    }
                }
            },
            'css-loader', // added this line
            {
                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                options: styles.getPostCssConfig({
                    themeImporter: {
                        themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark')
                    },
                    minify: true
                })
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Didn't work, but further research revealed this: https://github.com/WearyMonkey/ngtemplate-loader/issues/10. I realize the issue isn't directly related, but the code that's shown there is.

It looks like the JS functions I'm seeing are generated by webpack as part of a dynamic require method hidden somewhere in my implementation. And that dynamically required module is being packaged with my cpg.css. Emptying out cpg.scss changed nothing- so it isn't the content of the file that's triggering this misplaced dynamic require. It's something else.

Comment: Could be also this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/moment-package-add-some-javascript-in-my-css-file because the only package here is moment

Comment: Or https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/1976

Comment: Yep, I just found the same thing. Looks like it's just broken right now. Gotta track down all of my dynamic imports I guess.